# Grabcut mask values

Tags: c++, opencv

The documentation for GrabCut says this about the mask parameter:

> @param mask Input/output 8-bit single-channel mask. The mask is initialized by the function when
>    mode is set to GC_INIT_WITH_RECT. Its elements may have one of the cv::GrabCutClasses.

The first time I invoke grabCut it runs successfully and the mask is initialised. But the second time I do it, using the mask and mode == GC_INIT_WITH_MASK, I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (mask element value must be equal GC_BGD or GC_FGD or GC_PR_BGD or GC_PR_FGD) in checkMask, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp, line 337

The values in the mask matrix are either 0 or 255, when I was expecting 0-3. Does this make sense? I am doing anything wrong?